# How to set up a seamless proxy in Apache to get around my ISP's firewall?

Tags: apache, proxy

I'm really hoping someone can help me out with this because I've been at it for several days and I think I'm going crazy!

I'm trying to do what to me sounds like a stupidly simple thing. I want to set up a proxy server using Apache on a dedicated machine that I rent so that I can get around my ISPs nonsense firewall. I am aware that I could use a VPN, I don't want to do that for reasons that should hopefully become clear after I explain the details of what I want.

First of all, I don't want the proxy server to be used for every request. Only for the sites that are blocked by my ISP.

Suppose I try to access blockedsite.com/path/to/resource and it fails. I then simply want to change the URL in the address bar to proxy.myserver.com/proxy/blockedsite.com/path/to/resource and have Apache handle everything to provide me with a seamless experience. That means,

1. ProxyPassReverse should modify the response headers to use to the proxy server.
2. All URLs in the response body should be modified to use the proxy

Here's what I have so far:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName proxy.myserver.com

        ProxyRequests off

        ProxyPass /proxy/ http://
        ProxyPassReverse /proxy/ http://
        ProxyPassReverse /proxy/ https://

        ProxyHTMLURLMap http:// /proxy/
        ProxyHTMLURLMap https:// /proxy/

        <Location /proxy/>
                ProxyPassReverse /

                AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
                Substitute "s|</title>|</title><meta name='referrer' content='no-referrer' />|ni"

                ProxyHTMLEnable On
                #ProxyHTMLURLMap  /      /app1/
                RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

This setup works beautifully for URLs that don't try to redirect me elsewhere. But if for example I try to access `proxy.myserver.com/proxy/facebook.com` I am still being redirected on the client side to `https://www.facebook.com` instead of `https://proxy.myserver.com/proxy/www.facebook.com` as I would like. The extra weird thing is that when I set up my own test site which does nothing except redirect me to an HTTPS address, the ProxyPassReverse rule for HTTPS does actually seem to work... but not when I try to access sites like Facebook or Google.

I see no reason to ramble on about my issues, what I'm looking for is astoundingly simple: a transparent, seamless experience! Aside from sticking `proxy.myserver.com/proxy/` in front of the URL in the address bar, I shouldn't have to do anything else for it to work. Yet that is not the case and despite over a week of searching, I have found nothing online to help me with this. It's as if I'm the only person in the universe to want to create a simple proxy with Apache that actually works as a firewall-get-arounder.

Please can someone lend me a hand here?! Even just to tell me I'm going about this all wrong and should give up and install Squid or something??

Answer (score 1):

Your last paragraph contains the right answer. You should indeed just "install Squid or something". In particular, I'd recommend Apache Traffic Server - http://trafficserver.apache.org/ - this is exactly what it's made for.

While Apache httpd can do proxying, it's not it's primary function, and so there are always things that will end up being frustrating with it. We *could* get your above scenario working, but it's really not the right tool for the job.